# OneDrive granular GPO control (Fetch Files, etc) & domain behavior

Tags: onedrive, gpo

In Win 8.1 there were 3 OneDrive policies. 
In Win 10 there is but a singular global enable/disable policy.

Are more policies coming?  Is there/will there be policies for the fetch files/sync settings/sync folders features of Windows 10 OneDrive?  Do the registry manipulations used in 8.1 OneDrve GPOs work in 10?

In other words, in order to obtain more granular GPO control of the OneDrive settings, do I need to make my own custom ADMX file or will Microsoft be offering one that will meet my needs?

It appears based on the excerpt below from [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fetch-files-on-your-PC-70761550-519c-4d45-b780-5a613b2f8822) that there is/will be a GPO for 'Fetch Files' but I can't find it in the current release of Win 10.

> If the Fetch files setting is unavailable, it might be blocked by
>   Group Policy on your domain-joined computer. Please contact your
>   network administrator for more info.

I tried using Process Monitor while toggling the Fetch Files option, and it found a read attempt at HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\OneDrive\Remote Access but that key does not exist on my machine.

I can't determine what key is written when the setting is toggled

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 64-bit Windows, use the following reg setting to disable the "fetch files" feature in OneDrive.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\OneDrive\Remote Access]
"GPOEnabled"=dword:00000001

For 32-bit Windows, use the following reg setting to disable the "fetch files" feature in OneDrive.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\OneDrive\Remote Access]
"GPOEnabled"=dword:00000001

I tested the 64-bit reg setting and the fetch files option is removed from OneDrive settings.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Administrative-settings-for-the-OneDrive-for-Business-Next-Generation-Sync-Client-0ecb2cf5-8882-42b3-a6e9-be6bda30899c

Comment: Was this just an educated guess on your part?

Comment: I found a link about the administrative settings for the OneDrive for Business Next Generation Sync Client and was not sure if it was applicable for the OneDrive client until I tested.  I will add the link as a reference.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you very much!